# Auto Format Issue

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have to follow a particular coding standard, and I am having issues with netbeans formatting to one of the standards.

Here is how netbeans is formatting the code:

```
}else
{
```

Here is how I need it to format the code:

```
}
else
{
```

It does it for both `else` and `elseif`. Under Formatting in the Editor options, in the Braces category I have them all set to `New Line`, so why is it formatting the `else` and `elseif` on the same line as the closing brace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed a bit misleading.
Under the category "Alignment" there is a group of checkboxes for "New Lines". You need to check there the "else" checkbox.